# Can't await a task after the fact

Tags: c#, async-await, task

How can I fix this Task/Await code? I'm basically calling a method that returns a `Task` and `Awaiting` it later. First off, it says that `Awaited task returns no value` which it does (to me anyway).  Then it says it can't convert void to int.  How come?  Thanks in advance.

```
class Program
    {
        static async void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var tsk = First();
            int mynumb = await tsk;
            return;

        }
        static async Task<int> First()
        {
            return 2;  
        }


    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please can you edit the question and share the code directly? Screenshots of code are of little use to people behind corporate firewalls that block the image sharing site, and also to users with accessibility requirements.

Comment: Your code is nonsense.  The async method `First` must return a `Task`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable type is incorrect.

Change it to this:

```
Task<int> tsk = First();
```

or just use the `var` keyword

```
var tsk = First();
```

To remove the warning you need to make the `First()` method return a `Task<int>` like the following

```
static Task<int> First()
{
    return Task.FromResult(2);
}
```

From the code above, it does seem that none of this needs to be asynchronous, so if this is the case you are probably wasting your time here.

Comment: Just to add a small elaboration on an otherwise correct answer: `Task` is used for an async method that returns no value. `Task<T>` is used for an async method that returns a `T` value. `await` looks at the generic type (`T`) of your task to define its own returned type (if any). Because you used `Task`, _there is no return type_ for your task, it's `void`, and thus you are trying to assign a `void` to your `int` variable, which results in the error you're getting.

Comment: Thank you.  That did it.  But I still have the warning message saying `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.` (green line under the First()).  How do I get rid of that?

Comment: Thanks for that @Flater.

@Zuzlx The warning is because your `First()` method is not asyncrounous in nature. You are returning an `int` and not a `Task<int>`. You can use `return Task.FromResult(2);` to remove that warning

Comment: @JamieRees Thanks for all the help.  When I change to `return Task.FromResult(2)` i get `CS4016 Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'int' rather than 'Task<int>' `

Comment: You can do `return 2;` when the method is defined as `async`.  The `Task.FormResult` only works if you remove `async`.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Amazing how much you learn from 6 lines of code.